# ¿Cómo cargo una vista sin que se abra en otra pestaña?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tengo esto, Quiero que al pulsar el botón no me cargue en otra pestaña, ese es mi controlador, quien conoce como lo puedo hacer que no sea window.open()?

```
public function obtener_notificaciones_agil($data) {
        $this->load->model('pages_model');
        $info = $this->pages_model->obtener_info_notificacion();
        foreach ($info as $row){
            if($row){
                array_push($data,[
                    'nombre'=> $row['valor'],
                    'descripcion' => "encuesta disponible para realizar.", 
                    'cantidad'=> 1,
                    'accion' => "window.open('".base_url()."index.php/pasos_encuesta/".$row['id']."')"]);
                }
            } 
        return $data;
```

Answer (score 2):

Sin saber apenas de PHP, me he fijado en la action que utilizas y creo que es ahí donde va a estar la respuesta.

`window.location.replace` en lugar de `window.open` creo va a ser la solución.

Te dejo el link a la documentación de MDN.

[MDN window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

[MDN window.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace)

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, era lo que buscaba